# Doing the new donut tutorial dont know what step i did wrong but the bottom of my cup has no depth.can i add depth only to the base of the cup?

Tags: extrude, solidify-modifier

I tried extruding the bottom but thats not giving what i expected.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: please share your file           https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: hard to tell what happened, how did you extrude exactly?

Comment: i just figured it out.so i made aduplicate of the small circle at the base.moved it up a little bit along z axis.and then joined it with bridges.its not perfect but atleast its looking 3d.

Comment: as moonboots mentioned in the comments, it is very hard to tell what is happening. could you share your file or show what exactly you extruded?

Comment: I am not sure if that is the best way to solve your problem